# Adding IsWix templates to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wix, iswix

I'm been searching and investigating a lot, but since this is not my area of expertise I'm a little bit lost.

I have to create an Installer that deploys a static web to a IIS server.
After some investigation I started using Wix to create the installer and I discovered [isWix](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix).
The problem is that in the [instruction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgDf1kv8a-4) when he creates the installer project, he already has isWix integrated to visual studio.
He creates a IsWix solution and use use the isWix tool to do the scafolding.

I don't really follow how to add IsWix to my Visual studio.

Comment: Try re-launching Visual Studio first of all. That also might be an old video, I am not sure. Chris Painter will be sure to answer for sure (he made IsWiX). And lobbing you [some help resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130). And here is a [direct link](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/WebInstaller).

Comment: And [Chris's own IIS stuff](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials) (for others who see this). Check for **`"Launch IsWiX"`** in the Tools menu to launch IsWiX (with a WiX project open in Visual Studio).

Comment: I wrote this tutorial later.  Hopefully it'll help. https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you download the iswix.msi from [here](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix/releases) as you run through the installer there is an option to install the VS project templates. These are disabled by default, so you just need to enable them.

[image]

This should then give you the project templates as you're expecting to see.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That must be an old build of IsWiX.  The current one doesn't have WiX v3 and v4 as distinct features (they are part of the VS AddIn )   and all of the features default to be installed. (InstallLevel 1)